# Is there a way to get the list of new files after using AWS S3 Sync?

Tags: python, shell, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am using AWS S3 Sync to sync a local directory with a S3 bucket. This will copy new and updated files from the source directory to the destination. As an extra step, I would also want to have a list of new files that got synced into s3. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Isn't this kind of information typically found in the relevant documentation/manual?

Comment: well, if you're just using awscli, just read up on 'aws s3 sync'.  If you're using python only, use boto3.  Though I suspect it would be easier if you just used aws s3 sync, particularly making sure you have set up awscli properly

Answer (score 0):

Use `--dryrun` *before* you do the sync. That displays what it will do but don't modify anything. Then you can run the normal s3 sync to make the changes.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html